# Unicorn Meta Zoo #8: What does leadership look like in our communities?

Tags: discussion, podcast, unicorn-meta-zoo

Welcome to the Unicorn Meta Zoo, a podcast by members of the Stack
Exchange community team. If you want to avoid spoilers, jump
[straight to the audio](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/leadership.mp3).

#### Participants

[image: hairboat]
[image: Juan M]
[image: Jon Ericson]

We are talking about aspects of leadership in our communities.

#### Links

- Abby's definition of a leader reminds me of the
  [Potter Stewart test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it).
- Joel's book is [*Smart and Gets Things Done*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2007/06/05/smart-and-gets-things-done/).
- We set up a [Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) just for our
  moderators to share their wisdom and knowledge.
- Our elections uses a
  [single transferable vote system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/03/01/fair-elections-and-stv/) for taking your preferences into account.

#### Meta

"This is the [no touching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDCd.gif)
podcast." This is certainly correct since none of us are even in the
same state. If anyone ever asks you to explain a double entendre,
change the subject immediately as every word out of your mouth will
instantly take on an unintended sexual meaning.

My title really did change to
[Community Product Manager](https://jlericson.com/2019/05/02/community_product_manager.html). It's mostly ceremonial.

["Unfortunately, as you probably already know, people"](https://twitter.com/horse_ebooks/status/228032106859749377)
could be a leadership motto. It's tempting to blame folks for problems
we have as Community Managers. On the other hand, we benefit from
leaders empowering others to accomplish our goals. I am forever in
their debt.

#### What do you think?

[Take a listen](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/leadership.mp3) and respond in the answers below.

Comment: Is the [podcast wiki](https://github.com/unicorn-meta-zoo/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/wiki) completely dead now? I never listen to these things but might find it interesting to skim through the transcript ... unfortunately, as you probably already know, people have stopped updating those pages since #3 or #4.

Comment: @Randal'Thor considering this is the first I'm seeing it (that I recall) I'm guessing most users probably don't know that GitHub repo exists. Doubly so for people who aren't programmers who listen to the podcast and don't use GitHub at all.

Comment: @TylerH It used to be linked from the podcast announcement meta posts (which is how I know about it at all), but not in this one.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I tried to transcribe a bit but it needs a skill I obviously lack and I apologized for that in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/738?m=7775067). If you know anyone around that is better equipped please invite them to contribute.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I'd really like to have a transcript, but we don't really have a budget. (Not that I couldn't ask for one, but I'm holding off until I feel the podcast has gained a footing.) I included the link to the wiki for a while since I was hoping it'd get used by volunteers. Frankly, it's way more work than I would be willing to put in myself, so I really can't expect it of others. So when it seemed as if people weren't using it, I stopped putting it in the announcement. (For what it's worth, I believe we have plenty of written artifacts, so I wouldn't worry about missing out too much.)

Comment: @JonEricson Understood. My comment was less to ask for an "official" budgeted transcript from SO Inc than to remind everyone reading this meta post that there *is* a transcript page which they could help to edit and bring up to date. Fingers crossed for some helpful volunteers!

Answer (score 20):

In the podcast you talked about characteristics of leaders (and how that varies by where a site is in its lifecycle).  One you didn't mention that I tend to notice on small or young sites is community members who *help guide newcomers*.  This is most noticeable in helpful comments, but helpful *edits* are just as important (and sometimes require more work).  This kind of direct outreach can have a huge effect when a promising newcomer's first post doesn't start out as a good fit.

All the other things you mentioned -- reviews, meta participation (especially asking questions), voting, flagging, asking and answering questions -- are important in building the *site*.  A few things build the site *by building the active user base*, by lending that helping hand.  These are things I take note of, and I think you do too when appointing pro-tems, even if you didn't happen to mention it.

Comment: Re *"This kind of direct outreach can have a huge effect"*: Can you provide an example? (It can be an indirect reference, so it requires some effort to find - to prevent any meta effect.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen the activity of the two candidates in Writing's recent election comes to mind.  It's anecdotal, but we've seen increased engagement on the site this year, not *just* because of a contest we had, and I attribute that in part to this kind of assistance.  (Other users do this too, but an election is easier to point to.)

Comment: If we didn't say it, it was only because we thought it went without saying. ;-) Plenty of communities got off to great starts because one or two early contributors took on the role of community greeter. It's a real joy to watch when it happens.

Comment: @JonEricson I figured you didn't say it because it's hard to think of everything on the spur of the moment when the question is asked. :-)  (I assume I'm not the only person who finishes an interview or presentation or conversation and then says "oh yeah, I should have said that too, and that, and...".)